# Prove or disprove - graph doesn't exists

Tags: graphs

So, we have a directed graph G whose basis graph is connective.
I was asked to prove or disprove If its possible that for every DFS run on G, the output will be two trees containing all G vertices .
The only thing I could think of Is that graph like this cannon have a root (otherwise we could use DFS on the root and the output will be just one tree containing all G vertices).

Any Ideas?

thanks.

Comment: What's a connective basis graph?

Comment: If you remove the edges direction, the graph Is connective.

Comment: I think you mean "connected". What do you mean when you say that the output of a DFS visit will be **two** trees? Are you referring to the number of trees in the forest that you get if you iteratively run a DFS visit on all the vertices of $G$ that are not already discovered by a previous DFS visit?

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I mean.

Comment: That graph G doesn't exists such as for every DFS run, the forest will contain only 2 trees,

Comment: Hint: look at the DAG $H$ obtained by identifying the strongly connected components of $G$, then consider the sources of $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the question is - "Does there exists a directed graph $G=(V,E)$ (whose undirected version is connected) such that each DFS run on $G$ (preferably with different choices of root) always return exactly two trees?", then the answer is No.

Compress all SCCs into supernode, and let $G^*=(V^*, E^*)$ be resulting graph with $V^*=\{S_1,S_2,\ldots, S_k\}$. Each SCC ($S_i$'s) must have either an incoming edge or an outgoing edge. Now,

- At least one SCC must have a zero incoming edge (say it is $S_1$).
- At least one SCC must have a zero outgoing edge (say it is $S_k$).

If you take a root in SCC $S_k$ as compared to $S_1$, then DFS will give one more tree for sure.

Comment: This idea seems to work, although you have to ensure that $S_1\neq S_k$ and $S_k$ is reachable from $S_1$. It may be easier to consider taking roots in $S_1$ compared to a component that has an incoming edge from $S_1$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider a digraph with vertex set $\{a,b,c,d\}$ and arc set $\{ad, bd, cd\}$. The underlying undirected graph is connected (it's a star with vertex $d$ as its center). Running DFS on the digraph gives at least three edge-disjoint trees.